# Search in multiple specific post types

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic, search

I want search in specific multiple custom post types. I using second code to determine post types:

```
function custom_search_filter($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ($query->is_search) {
              $query->set('post_type', array('post','product'));
        }
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_search_filter');
```

I can not search for woocommerce products, if in array post_type is more than only 'product' cpt. If is only 'product' then this post type is findable.

In my search.php file code is:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        founded 
    <? endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

If in array('post','page'), all is working good too, posts and pages are findable.

Comment: I suspect that Woocommerce change the `WP_Query` object with `WC_Query` when querying for products. Have you tried to add your action later? `add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_search_filter', 90);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem and it had something to do with the query's `posts_per_page` parameter. Try setting it explicitly, like so:

```
function custom_search_filter($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ($query->is_search) {
              $query->set('posts_per_page', 10 ); // Try setting it to the number you've set in the Wordpress admin (Settings > Reading). 
              $query->set('post_type', array('post','product'));
        }
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_search_filter');
```

Hope this helps!